# Why can't I use map on the result of a querySelectorAll?

Tags: javascript

I recently needed to extract the value of several nodes from an HTML document. I got the nodes using querySelectorAll, which returns a list of the nodes that meet the criteria. I had used arr.map before, so I tried to do it like this (which did not work):

```js
var elems = document.querySelectorAll('select option:checked');
values = elems.map(function(obj) {return obj.value});
```

When I read the documentation in MDN, I saw that I had to use something like this instead:

```js
var elems = document.querySelectorAll('select option:checked');
var values = Array.prototype.map.call(elems, function(obj) {
  return obj.value;
});
```

My question is, if what I get from querySelectorAll is an array, why can't I use the first expression, like I would for any other array?

Comment: `querySelectorAll` does not return array, it returns `array-like-object`. If you are referring docs, read it completely...

Comment: [___Why is `NodeList` not an Array?___](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList#Why_is_NodeList_not_an_Array)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> My question is, if what I get from querySelectorAll is an array, why can't I use the first expression, like I would for any other array?

`querySelectorAll` does **not** return an array, it returns a [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList).

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) (emphasis mine):

> Returns a list of the elements within the document (using depth-first pre-order traversal of the document's nodes) that match the specified group of selectors. **The object returned is a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList).**

`NodeList` does not have `Array.prototype` in its prototype chain, so it doesn't have the array methods.

Comment: Hmm, I assumed it was an array, I'm reading about NodeLists right now. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: You can create an array from a NodeList with Array.from(), eg. `const values = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("input")).map(input => input.value);`

Answer (score 5):

As others pointed out, a node list (querySelectorAll) is not the same as an Array.  With ES6 you can do this as a one liner with the spread operator (which converts to an array):

```
const checkedOptions = [...document.querySelectorAll('select option:checked')].map(option => option.value);
```

Comment: The answer come a few years late, haha. That's what I've been using for a while, it's a lot more convenient. Still, it will most likely help other people searching that right now.